# Configuración de idioma bajo la que se ejecuta xp_cmdshell

Tags: configuración, idioma

Utilizo esta función para generar un fichero plazo con la salida del comando DIR para todas mis unidades de disco.

Para ello creo con XP-CMDSHELL un fichero .bat.

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo CHCP 65001                > C:\...\carga.bat';
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo dir C:\*.* /s /t:w /-c   ^> C:\...\entrada.txt >> C:\...\carga.bat';
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo dir D:\*.* /s /t:w /-c ^>^> C:\...\entrada.txt >> C:\...\carga.bat';
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo dir F:\*.* /s /t:w /-c ^>^> C:\...\entrada.txt >> C:\...\carga.bat';
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo dir G:\*.* /s /t:w /-c ^>^> C:\...\entrada.txt >> C:\...\carga.bat';
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo dir H:\*.* /s /t:w /-c ^>^> C:\...\entrada.txt >> C:\...\carga.bat';
```

Posteriormente ejecuto el fichero bat:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\...\carga.bat';
```

Posteriormente cargo el fichero plazo en SQL con BULK INSERT:

```
BULK INSERT directorio.dbo.entrada FROM N'C:\...\entrada.txt' with (CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar');
```

Una vez en SQL trato el fichero para componer un inventario con todos mis archivos, para lo cual identifico filas claves en función de la aparición de textos como *' Directorio de '*, *'El volumen de la unidad'*, etc. (procedimiento artesano, pero funciona).

En días pasados me vi obligado a restaurar Windows (y volver a instalarlo todo).

Cuando repito el procedimiento veo que me falla la parte del tratamiento del fichero importado.

Observo el fichero placo generado con el .bat y veo que las expresiones reseñadas están en inglés (*Directory of*, etc.).

Lo curioso es que si ejecuto el fichero .bat a mano, la salida utiliza las expresiones en español, mientras que si lo ejecuto empleando XP-CMDSHELL desde SQL-SERVER se registran en inglés.

¿Alguna idea sobre cómo modificar la configuración de idioma con la que se ejecuta XP-CMDSHELL (u otro forma de corregir el problema)?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El tema es la configuración regional del usuario con el que se inicial el servicio. Como tienes acceso a ejecutar el `xp_cmdshell` te sugiero ejecutar esto para obtener la configuración regional del usuario con el que se inicia el servidor SQL:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'reg export "HKCU\Control Panel\International" <path_a_definir>\regional.reg'
```

`<path_a_definir>` tiene que ser una carpeta local o de red, a la que el SQL Server tenga permisos de escritura y por otro lados puedas acceder para editar el archivo. Si todo funciona bien tendrás un `regional.reg` similar a esto:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"Locale"="00000409"
"LocaleName"="en-US"
"s1159"="AM"
"s2359"="PM"
"sCountry"="United States"
"sCurrency"="$"
"sDate"="-"
"sDecimal"="."
"sGrouping"="3;0"
"sLanguage"="ENU"
"sList"=","
"sLongDate"="dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"
"sMonDecimalSep"="."
"sMonGrouping"="3;0"
"sMonThousandSep"=","
"sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
"sNegativeSign"="-"
"sPositiveSign"=""
"sShortDate"="yyyy-MM-dd"
"sThousand"=","
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
"sShortTime"="HH:mm"
"sYearMonth"="MMMM yyyy"
"iCalendarType"="1"
"iCountry"="1"
"iCurrDigits"="2"
"iCurrency"="0"
"iDate"="2"
"iDigits"="2"
"NumShape"="1"
"iFirstDayOfWeek"="6"
"iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
"iLZero"="1"
"iMeasure"="1"
"iNegCurr"="0"
"iNegNumber"="1"
"iPaperSize"="1"
"iTime"="1"
"iTimePrefix"="0"
"iTLZero"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo]
"Nation"="244"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile]
"Languages"=hex(7):65,00,6e,00,2d,00,55,00,53,00,00,00
"ShowAutoCorrection"=dword:00000001
"ShowTextPrediction"=dword:00000001
"ShowCasing"=dword:00000001
"ShowShiftLock"=dword:00000001
"UserLocaleFromLanguageProfileOptOut"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile\en-US]
"0409:00000409"=dword:00000001
```

Tendrías que editar eventualmente lo valores, revisando la registry de un equipo con la localización adecuada o mucho mejor aplicar este procedimiento en un servidor que este correctamente configurado para "clonar" esta configuración. Finalmente teniendo un `regional.reg` con los valores adecuados, simplemente puedes aplicarlos mediante:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'reg import <path_a_definir>\regional.reg'
```

Por supuesto también podrías hacer lo mismo si el usuario del servicio puede tener un acceso intercativo, pero este metodo es más sencillo y cómodo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la idea. Me ha llevado a revisar previamente la configuración regional y comprobar que estaba definida "para nuevos usuarios" en inglés EEUU. He probado a cambiarla y ya funciona.